# Debugging Lisp & SLIME, error "Cannot find source location"

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

I am wrote the code with bugs.

Example:

```
(print (/ 1 0))
```

I am trying compile with C-c C-c.
And catch the error with stack frame.

I want see line in the code where an error occured. Clicked 'v' on line in stack frame and catched error.

```
Error: Cannot find source location for: #<COMPILED-CODE-LOCATION 
(SB-C::VARARGS-ENTRY /)>
```

How can I go to the line in my code?

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean, you're compiling with C-c C-c? Is that key combination bound to slime-compile-file?

Comment: `C-c C-c` - Compile the top-level form at point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the error, the line you want to jump to, is somewhere in package `SB-C`, which is part of SBCL. If you don't have SBCL sources (you've installed a binary or deleted them), you should get them (relevant to your current SBCL version) and then link them up in `.sbclrc` like this (according to http://www.cliki.net/SLIME%20Features):

```
(setf (logical-pathname-translations "SYS") 
      '(("SYS:SRC;**;*.*.*" #P"/opt/sbcl/src/**/*.*")
        ("SYS:CONTRIB;**;*.*.*" #P"/opt/sbcl/contrib/**/*.*")))
```

Or just compile SBCL from source and it will know, where they are.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused and do not add correct a error, I fix it.

Comment: Anyway, the solution should be the same.

Comment: Set up (sb-ext:set-sbcl-source-location "/path/to/sbcl/source/") in .sbclrc. Source: Finding SBCL sources [link](http://xach.livejournal.com/300290.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have (proclaim '(optimize debug)) above that line somewhere?  This function will ensure that your system has all the debugging data it can get.